# How to convert this microsoft excel query to get the next day data every time I run it?

Tags: sql, excel

I need help in recoding this SQL script below to get the next day data every time I run it.

```
SELECT "Dr_ Jaminelli Banks, DPM Schedule CALIFORNIA__1766292526000004s_(WOUND PROS SCHEDULES/CALIFORNIA CLINICAL STAFF SCHEDULE)_0".Address, "Dr_ Jaminelli Banks, DPM Schedule CALIFORNIA__1766292526000004s_(WOUND PROS SCHEDULES/CALIFORNIA CLINICAL STAFF SCHEDULE)_0".Alias
FROM "Dr_ Jaminelli Banks, DPM Schedule CALIFORNIA__1766292526000004s_(WOUND PROS SCHEDULES/CALIFORNIA CLINICAL STAFF SCHEDULE)" "Dr_ Jaminelli Banks, DPM Schedule CALIFORNIA__1766292526000004s_(WOUND PROS SCHEDULES/CALIFORNIA CLINICAL STAFF SCHEDULE)_0"
WHERE  "Dr_ Jaminelli Banks, DPM Schedule CALIFORNIA__1766292526000004s_(WOUND PROS SCHEDULES/CALIFORNIA CLINICAL STAFF SCHEDULE)_0"."Next Visit date" =Date()
```

Comment: Please share your attempts

Answer (score 0):

Dateadd function should work for you. In the WHERE clause change
=Date()
to
=Dateadd(day,1,Date())

Comment: Did not work. Error says day1 is not column